# how to delete file from the server after downloading it ?or how can i store the file to client machine directly from output stream?

Tags: client, save, download, portlet, liferay-6

am using liferay custom portlet and in that am using jasper report now my problem is that how can i download the pdf report directly on the client machine

right now am storing the file at server first.then provide url for downloading the pdf to user.but how can i directly store the file to client machine if i have pdf file's outputstream .

ot if i can know some how when user click on the download link and after downloading the file if i want to delete the donlowded file from the server then how can i do it.?if any one can guide me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking for is possible, but I would be interested in seeing someone correct that statement though.

Servers really shouldn't be directly storing files on a client machine as that violates the intent of the client server relationship. A client has to make a request for the file and then the client can save that file (eg like a ftp download). Servers just don't manipulate client machines as they see fit.

As far as knowing when a file is downloaded, there isn't anything in a portlet you can do to detect that. You can use ResourceRequest and serveResource method to serve a file, but nothing in the portlet API will inform your portlet that the download is complete or that it wasn't interrupted by something.

As an alternative you might try simply having a cron job that will clean out old files. In this case, make sure to inform users how long they have to successfully download the file.